# how to hide a password that's written inside a python code?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, password-protection

I have a script that should access a firewall admin page to do some stuff and the script runs automatically so I need to save username/password somewhere in the local machine or within the code itself.

note that I'm not the admin of the local machine so I can't have full permission on a configuration file where the script can get the credentials.

also note if I encrypted the password, I wouldn't be able to decrypt it before logging in the firewall admin page. ( I don't have this option available to store the decryption key inside the firewall).

is converting the script into an exe file using pyinstaller would be enough to hide the password (by hiding the source code itself ? if not then what would you suggest?

thanks

Comment: No, use encryption like `AES` etc or hashing function like `bcrypt`

Comment: No pyinstaller will not 100% hide the password. If you don't care too much about security you can encode it/look into encrypting it.

Comment: if I encrypted it, how I can I store the decryption key safely and out of the hands of the windows' admin employees? as I can't decrypt it from the firewall side.

Comment: @MuhammadLebda can you not make the decryption key file password protected?

Comment: What you're trying isn't going to work. You can't render the password both accessible to the script and inaccessible to the admin under these constraints.

Comment: @Insula the windows admin have full permissions on the windows server, so storing it locally wouldn't be safe.

Comment: You'd also just be able to set permissions to execute only.

Answer (score 0):

I Know it's too late but this for next one search for a solution ,
You can save any passwords or encryption keys anything can python variable contain in the main script or in any file and add it to .spec as data because main_script.py or datas not visible in MEIPASS in tmp folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).